# Does the Facebook Scribe Server support authenticating its clients and securing the client/server connection?

Tags: amazon-ec2, logging, heroku, scribe

I plan on running a Facebook Scribe Server on an AWS EC2 providing logging services to several Heroku hosted Rails clients.

Is there a mechanism to authenticate Scribe clients in cloud-based scenarios like one described above? If so, can the resulting connections be secured using SSL?